# downloading a csv from ftp site using the webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, csv, ftp

I have the following code.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
Do
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Count - 1
        If Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).InnerHtml.StartsWith("APX Power UK RPD historical data") Then
            Dim link As String
            link = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).GetAttribute("href")

            WebBrowser2.Navigate(link)
            WebBrowser1.Dispose()

            Exit Do
        End If
    Next
Loop
End Sub
```

IT finds a link on a page and sends a click to it, this navigates to a ftp site.[image]

I want to download the file HH_Only_rpd.csv to c:/temp automatically.

I have been experimenting with `webclient` but I have hit a wall.  I can navigate straight to the file using `WebBrowser1.Navigate("ftp://ae.rpduser:freedata@ftp.apxgroup.com/HH_ONLY_rpd.csv")` but I get a save as dialog box that I don't want as I need it all to be silent as I am going to automate it.

I am using VS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

> I need it all to be silent

Then use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class, not the `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 0):

after much research I used a console application with the following code.

```
Imports System.Net
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim wc As New WebClient
            wc.DownloadFile(New Uri("ftp://ae.rpduser:freedata@ftp.apxgroup.com/HH_ONLY_rpd.csv"), "c:\Temp\test.csv")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```